# SQL Update: the row such that...?

Tags: mysql

Suppose f is a string function such as concatenation by 0: f(0011)=00110.

Suppose `mytable` has columns `string` which is an index, and `price`.

I would like to do something like the following pseudo-code:

```
UPDATE mytable SET price(X)=0.5 FOR ALL THOSE ROWS X SUCH THAT
THE ROW Y SUCH THAT THE `string` OF Y equals f(the `string` FOR X)
HAS price(Y)=0
```

More generally, how can I reference

> "the row such that [condition-holds-that-depends-on-the-current-row]"

in (My)SQL?

Comment: I guess trigger would work here

Comment: Whoa... not super easy then?

Comment: This should just be a `WHERE` clause, maybe with a self-join. I'm not really sure I understand the condition, can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: You only need a trigger if you need to make this happen whenever you change `price(Y)`. But I don't think triggers are allowed to update the same table that triggers them, because that could recurse infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup demo

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
( id         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, thestring  VARCHAR(32)
, price      DECIMAL(11,2)
) ENGINE=INNODB
;
INSERT INTO mytable (id, thestring, price) VALUES
 ( 1,'0011'   , 123.45)
,( 2,'00110'  ,  45.67)
,( 3,'001100' ,   0.00)   
,( 4,'10'     ,   4.44)
,( 5,'100'    ,   5.55)
,( 6,'1000'   ,   0.00)
;
```

Write a query that identifies the Y rows in mytable

```
SELECT y.*
  FROM `mytable` `y` 
 WHERE y.price = 0.0 
 ORDER BY y.id
```

Add a join to mytable to find the matching X rows

```
SELECT x.id         AS x_id
     , x.thestring  AS x_thestring 
     , x.price      AS x_price
     , y.id         AS y_id 
     , y.thestring  AS y_thestring
     , y.price      AS y_price
  FROM mytable `y`
  JOIN mytable `x` 
    ON CONCAT(x.thestring,'0') = y.thestring 
 WHERE y.price = 0.0 
 ORDER BY y.id
```

Convert the SELECT into an UPDATE.  (Replace SELECT ... FROM with UPDATE, and add a SET clause before the WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE mytable `y`
  JOIN mytable `x` 
    ON CONCAT(x.thestring,'0') = y.thestring
   SET x.price = 0.5
 WHERE y.price = 0.0
```

Just replace the `CONCAT(x.thestring,'0')` with `f(x.thestring)`.

---

Another option is to use a correlated subquery.

First, write a SELECT

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM mytable `x`
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable `y`
                 WHERE y.thestring = f(x.thestring)
                   AND y.price = 0.00
              )
```

And then convert that to an UPDATE. Replace `SELECT ... FROM` with the `UPDATE` keyword, and add a `SET` clause before the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE mytable `x`
   SET x.price = 0.5
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable `y`
                 WHERE y.thestring = f(x.thestring)
                   AND y.price = 0.00
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `UPDATE` with a self-join.

```
UPDATE mytable AS x
JOIN mytable AS y ON y.string = f(x.string)
SET x.price = 0.5
WHERE y.price = 0
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice.